# M.2 B-Key to USB implementation

Tags: pcb-design, usb, adapter, high-speed, m.2

I can’t seem to find much documentation on the M.2 standard or typical implementation schematics. I am currently working on a board for the raspberry pi in order to add cellular LTE/5G capabilities to the device. (normally I would just use a HAT that is already in production but cellular is only one of the features I plan to implement so this is something I need to make myself.)

The pi4 doesn’t have PCIe exposed from its GPIO headers so I plan on using a short USB cable to use the USB-3.0 ports on the front of the board. However, I can not find any examples or documentation on how USB-3.0 to M.2 B-key adapters are typically implemented. Does anyone know how this design is commonly done, or how popular adapters are designed?

This question is similar to one that was closed for asking for off-site resources, but I thought I’d rephrase the question to ask if anyone here knows the answer instead.